# Convert long data to wide data with multiple columns and multiple values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame of 300K rows with 2 main columns of interest. (NAME & SUBJCT) I need to convert this data into a wide format and in addition, if I get a records for a particular subject with multiple dates, I need to place them next to each other.
I tried using `tidyr::pivot_wider` but I'm not able to get it work.

Sample data:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  NAME = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC"), 
  SUBJECT = c("MATHS", "LANGUAGE 1", "LANGUAGE 1", "LANGUAGE 2","LANGUAGE 2","LANGUAGE 2","LANGUAGE 2", "SCIENCE", "SCIENCE", "HISTORY", "PE", "ENVIRONMENT", "COMPUTERS", "COMPUTERS", "COMPUTERS", "BIOLOGY", "SANSKRIT"), 
  YEAR = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2013"), 
  MARKS = c("45", "48", "47", "44", "48", "46", "42", "42", "43", "37", "42", "43", "42", "41", "44", "41", "44"), 
  MAXIMUM = c("46", rep("50", 5), "45", "50", rep("45", 9))
)
> DF
   NAME     SUBJECT YEAR MARKS MAXIMUM
1   ABC       MATHS 2010    45      46
2   ABC  LANGUAGE 1 2011    48      50
3   DEF  LANGUAGE 1 2012    47      50
4   ABC  LANGUAGE 2 2013    44      50
5   ABC  LANGUAGE 2 2014    48      50
6   ABC  LANGUAGE 2 2015    46      50
7   DEF  LANGUAGE 2 2013    42      45
8   ABC     SCIENCE 2015    42      50
9   DEF     SCIENCE 2016    43      45
10  ABC     HISTORY 2016    37      45
11  DEF          PE 2017    42      45
12  DEF ENVIRONMENT 2015    43      45
13  DEF   COMPUTERS 2016    42      45
14  DEF   COMPUTERS 2017    41      45
15  DEF   COMPUTERS 2018    44      45
16  DEF     BIOLOGY 2015    41      45
17  ABC    SANSKRIT 2013    44      45
```

My expected output is like this: (It is a bit long)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit tricky with pivoting twice, but here you go:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% 
  group_by(NAME, SUBJECT) %>% 
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("YEAR", "MARKS", "MAXIMUM")) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0(name, ind)) %>% 
  select(-ind) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("SUBJECT", "name"), values_from = "value")
```

Comment: Thank you. this is perfect. Any resources where I can learn more about tidyverse pivot functions ?

Comment: The docs [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) and [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html), maybe [r4ds](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-tidy.html#how-does-pivot_wider-work), but I would suggest to play around with it a bit until you feel comfortable,